# How to declare a Named Volume in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If I use `VOLUME` in a docker file, it creates an anonymous volume. Is there any way to create a named volume from the dockerfile?

I'm looking for the Dockerfile equivalent of

```
docker run -v my-named-volume:/mnt/something repo/my-img
```

All I've managed to get via a Dockerfile is the equivalent of

```
docker run -v /mnt/something repo/my-img
```

I would think it is just not supported; however, [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) says this

> The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with **the specified name** and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or other containers.

It seems to imply that there is a way to name the volume, but it doesn't say how

Comment: Short answer, this is not possible *by design* You may find helpfull [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30647#issuecomment-276882545) post to understand why

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible. I think the docs are worded maybe misleadingly.

“The specified name” refers to the path / directory name at which the volume will be created.

Answer (score 12):

This [issue comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30647#issuecomment-276882545) explains the current landscape better than the docs do.

> This is by design. Let me try to explain; the VOLUME directive in the Dockerfile only defines that a volume should be created for a specific path in the image (/container when running). The name of the volume should never be dictated by an image, because that's something that should be defined at runtime

Answer (score 9):

It is a bit unclear. It creates a mount point using that name but the actual file path does not use that name. If you do a `docker inspect {container-name}`, you will see the name like: `"Destination": "/mnt/something",` and the actual location like: `"Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/cb80c7802244dd3669eed8afb7d94b61366844d80677eb180fa12002db04ea7c/_data",`.

This is because the Dockerfile isn't tied to a particular host and can't be sure the host volume path would exist. You need to do that in the `run` (or equivalent) statement. You can use the api or `docker inspect` to  find out where the volume is located once the container is created if you needed to use that info in a script or similar.

Declaring the volume in the Dockerfile insures that the data will persist and will be available to the host -- even if the location isn't preset.

Comment: "even if the location isn't preset":

That statement is core reason to define volume within `Dockerfile`. 

Also, this will ensure data will survive container restart even if binding is not defined on `docker run` or in `docker-compose`